# Avoiding error when using rename in dplyr and column doesn't exist

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a clever way to use the rename function in dplyr when in some instances the column to be renamed doesn't exist?

For example, I would like the following not to result in an error

```
mtcars%>%rename(miles_per_gallon=mpg,missing_varible=foo)
```

(results in this: Error: Unknown variables: foo.)

but rather the dataframe with all possible renaming done.

Currently I am explicitly checking that the specific column exists before renaming

Thanks

Iain

Comment: Why would you want to rename a column that doesn't exist?

Comment: Not all attributes (columns) exist for all objects (rows) that I am working with. This means if I subset the data in a particular way I can end up with a data frame that has fewer columns than I expect - hence the explicit checking

Comment: In fact, this is not an uncommon problem in code that is reused or shared, but accepts input from others.  I've added one more solution @Iain

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sometimes it's okay to not do everything in `dplyr`.  This may be one of those times.  I would set up a vector that operates as a key:

```
namekey <- c(mpg="miles_per_gallon", cyl="cylinders", disp="displacement", hp="horse_power",
             drat="rear_axle_ratio", wt="weight", qsec="quarter_mile_time", vs="v_s",
             am="transmission", gear="number_of_gears", carb="number_of_carburetors",
             foo="missing_variable")

mtcars1 <- mtcars[,1:2]
mtcars1$foo <- rnorm(nrow(mtcars1))

names(mtcars1) <- namekey[names(mtcars1)]

head(mtcars1)
#                   miles_per_gallon cylinders missing_variable
# Mazda RX4                     21.0         6       -0.9901081
# Mazda RX4 Wag                 21.0         6        0.2338014
# Datsun 710                    22.8         4       -0.3077473
# Hornet 4 Drive                21.4         6        1.1200518
# Hornet Sportabout             18.7         8        0.7482842
# Valiant                       18.1         6        0.4206614
```

Once you have your key, it's just a single, easy-to-understand line of code that does the rename.

Comment: It may be OK, but it is still nice to try and keep everything within a single paradigm :)

Comment: @Maxim.K `dplyr` is a paradigm that includes base R.  This is a base R solution, so in that sense it is still in a single paradigm.  This just doesn't rely on any of the add on solutions that `dplyr` brings to the game.

Comment: This only works when all the columns are in the `namekey` vector. If one is missing, there is no error, but it also renamed as "NA".  The `plyr` answer from @wibeasley lets you do it without losing unknown column names: `plyr::rename( mtcars1, replace=namekey, warn_missing=F)`

Answer (score 46):

Perhaps not the intention of the designers, but you can utilize the scoped verb `rename_all` and the `dplyr` function `recode`, which takes one or more key value pairs like `old_name = "New Name"`.

```r
library(dplyr)

rename_all(iris, recode, Sepal.Length = "sepal_length", cyl = "cylinder")
#     sepal_length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
# 4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
# 5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa
# 7            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa
# 8            5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa
# 9            4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa
```

Comment: `rename_all` has been superseded with `rename_with` in the current `dplyr` life cycle.

Answer (score 13):

#### Revised advice in 2023:

I suggest using a modern function (like [`dplyr::rename_with()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rename.html), as advocated by other answers here) and avoid loading an old package like plyr just for this function.

#### Original 2015 post:

The [`plyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html) package has a [`rename()`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plyr/docs/rename) function with a `warn_missing` parameter.

```
plyr::rename(
  mtcars, 
  replace      = c(mpg="miles_per_gallon", foo="missing_varible"),
  warn_missing = FALSE
)
```

If you use it, consider using `requireNamespace()` [instead of](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#search-path) `library()`, so its function names don't collide with dplyr's.

Answer (score 8):

To expand on Captain Tyler's mention of `rename_with`, if you have (potentially) more than one variable to rename, I find this solution using `case_when` works well and is easy to read:

```
iris %>%
    rename_with(
        ~ case_when(
            . == "Petal.Width" ~ "NewPetalWidthName",
            . == "NotActuallyThere" ~ "DoNothing",
            TRUE ~ .
        )
    ) %>%
    head()
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `rename_at()` to accomplish this:

```
mtcars %>%
  rename_at(vars(matches("^missing_var$")), function(x) "foo")
```

Doesn't return an error if "missing_var" isn't in your data.frame.
If you want to replace multiple variables that may or may not exist, you can put the original and new names in a named vector/list, write a short little function to return the new variable name.

```
customRename <- function(orig_name) {
  renames <- c(
    foo = "OOF",
    bar = "RAB",
    fi = "IF")
  renames[[orig_name]]
}

mtcar %>%
  rename_at(vars(matches("^foo$|^bar$|^fi$")), customRename)
```

Comment: With the last version of dplyr, rename_at has been replaced by the use of across.        `mtcars %>% rename(across(matches("^missing_var$"), ~ { "foo"}))`

Answer (score 4):

One more solution that can safely operate within dplyr without throwing an error using conditional evaluation {}.  This will apply the rename if "foo" exists, but continue execution with the original df in the absence of a column named "foo".

```
mtcars %>%
{if("foo" %in% names(.)) rename(., missing_varible=foo) else .} %>%
rename(miles_per_gallon=mpg)
```

Answer (score 4):

They have now mentioned the use of `rename_with`

`mtcars %>% rename_with( ~"missing_varible", "foo")`

Please see the help for more details.

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work? Returns: `Error in stop_subscript(): ! Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Column foo doesn't exist.`

Answer (score 3):

First, define a list with your column names you want to rename in a data frame df.

```
columnNamesToRename <-
    list(
      newColumnName1 = "oldColumnName1",
      newColumnName2 = "oldColumnName2"
    )
```

Next, remove the elements of the list, which have a column name as their name, but is not a column name of your data frame:

```
columnNamesToRename.WhichAreColumnNamesInTibble <-
columnNamesToRename[columnNamesToRename %in% intersect(
  unlist(columnNamesToRename),
  colnames(df)
)]
```

Then, you can rename the column names using the named list columnNamesToRename.WhichAreColumnNamesInTibble:

```
df.WithRenamedColumnNames <-
    df %>% dplyr::rename(!!!columnNamesToRename.WhichAreColumnNamesInTibble)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way:

```r
library(magrittr) # for `%>% `
library(dplyr) # for `rename_with`

mt <- mtcars[1:3, 1:4]
mt
#>                 mpg cyl disp  hp
#> Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110
#> Datsun 710     22.8   4  108  93

# c(old_column_name = "new_column_name")
column_recodes <- c(mpg = "miles_per_gallon", 
                    hp = "Horse Power",
                    missing_varible = "foo", 
                    `Another non-existent column name` = "bar")

mt %>% rename_with(~recode(., !!!column_recodes))
#>                miles_per_gallon cyl disp Horse Power
#> Mazda RX4                  21.0   6  160         110
#> Mazda RX4 Wag              21.0   6  160         110
#> Datsun 710                 22.8   4  108          93
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a new verb for dplyr, 'any_of', which you can use. you also need to put the original names in strings

```
rename_key = c(miles_per_gallon='mpg', missing_varible='foo')
mtcars %>% rename(any_of(rename_key))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a crisp dplyr solution:

`mtcars %>% rename_with(~"missing_varible", matches("foo"))`