# Function that ignores missing columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have the following two data frames:

```
col1 <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
col2 <- c("A","B","C","D","E")

col1a <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
col2a <- c("A","B","C","D","E")

df1 <- data.frame(col1, col2)
df2 <- data.frame(col1a, col2a)

colnames(df1) <- c("c1","c2")
colnames(df2) <- c("c1","c3")
```

And I have the following function to rename column headers:

```
library(dplyr)

col_rename <- function(x) x %>% rename(new_c1 = c1, new_c2 = c2, new_c3 = c3)
```

When I run this function, I get an error because the columns in the function does not match the columns in the data frame.

```
df1 <- col_rename(df1)
Error: `c3` contains unknown variables
```

How can I make the function run only on the present columns, and ignore the ones not present, without removing or changing the column names specified in the function?

EDIT:

I can see how the example was a bit confusing. I have many dataframes with many columns. These columns are shared by some dataframes but not all. However, I want to rename all columns specified by the function, regardless of what is present in the dataframe. It looks something like this:

```
col1 <- c(1:5)
col2 <- c(1:5)
col3 <- c(1:5)
col4 <- c(1:5)


df1 <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4)
df2 <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4)

colnames(df1) <- c("c1","c2","c6","c8")
colnames(df2) <- c("c1","c3","c2","c8")

AB_rename <- function(x) x %>% rename(aa=col1,bb=col2,                      
                                      cc=col3,dd=col4,
                                      ee=col5,ff=col6,
                                      gg=col7,hh=col8)
```

Therefore I cannot follow the example of @Ycw, as they do not all follow the same rename rule. How do I make this ignore columns that are not present?

Comment: Create an object and pass it as argument

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoiding error when using rename in dplyr and column doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34275576/avoiding-error-when-using-rename-in-dplyr-and-column-doesnt-exist)

Comment: @Haakonkas I have updated my post to reflect your new question. By the way, it is not ideal to change your original question a lot after you posted it. Please refine your question before posting it next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a workaround to use `setNames` for the `col_rename` function.

```
col_rename <- function(x) setNames(x, paste0("new_", names(x)))

col_rename(df1)
  new_c1 new_c2
1      a      A
2      b      B
3      c      C
4      d      D
5      e      E

col_rename(df2)
  new_c1 new_c3
1      a      A
2      b      B
3      c      C
4      d      D
5      e      E
```

Or use the `select_all` function from the `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% select_all(function(x) paste0("new_", x))
  new_c1 new_c2
1      a      A
2      b      B
3      c      C
4      d      D
5      e      E
```

This (`~`) also works for `select_all`

```
df2 %>% select_all(~paste0("new_", .))
  new_c1 new_c3
1      a      A
2      b      B
3      c      C
4      d      D
5      e      E
```

`rename_all` also works well

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% rename_all(~paste0("new_", .))
  new_c1 new_c2
1      a      A
2      b      B
3      c      C
4      d      D
5      e      E
```

#### Update

This is an update to address OP's updated question.

We can create a named vector showing the relationship between old column names and new column names. And defined a function to change the name based on the `setNames` function.

```
# Create name vector
vec <- paste0("c", 1:8)
names(vec) <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", "gg", "hh")

# Create the function
AB_rename <- function(x, name_vec){
  old_colname <- names(x)
  new_colname <- name_vec[name_vec %in% old_colname]
  x2 <- setNames(x, names(new_colname))
  return(x2)
}

AB_rename(df1, vec)
  aa bb ff hh
1  1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4  4
5  5  5  5  5
```

Comment: @d.b Thanks for your comment. Are you thinking like `name_vec[match(old_colname, name_vec)]`?