# Rename only if field exists, otherwise ignore

Tags: r, dplyr

One can rename a field:

```
mtcars %>% rename(bla = mpg)
```

But if the field doesn't exist, an error:

```
    mtcars %>% rename(MPG = mpg, CYL = cyl, bla = uyhgfrtgf)
Error: Can't rename columns that don't exist.
x Column `uyhgfrtgf` doesn't exist
```

I looked at `?rename_if` and it says this is now superseded by `rename_with()`.

What's the 'right' way to attempt to rename fields but with a possibility they don't exist (e.g. in this case a ShinyApp with filter selectors).

Comment: Also see [Avoiding error when using rename in dplyr and column doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34275576/1082435)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Use `any_of()` with a named vector.  `any_of()` doesn't error if a variable isn't found.

```
library(dplyr)

lookup <- c(MPG = "mpg", CYL = "cyl", bla = "uyhgfrtgf")

mtcars %>%
   rename(any_of(lookup))

                   MPG CYL disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
...
```

Comment: Are you aware of an base R approach as well? If so, could you please refer to?

Answer (score 11):

I'm pretty sure you can do this with NSE but I can't handle this (yet?).

So you could define a lookup variable first:

```r
lookup <- c("mpg" = "MPG", "cyl" = "CYL", "uyhgfrtgf" = "bla")
```

Attention: it's the other way round as in your `rename` function.

Now you could use

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rename_with(.fn = ~lookup[.x], .cols = intersect(names(.), names(lookup)))
```

which returns

```r
                     MPG CYL  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
```

Comment: Thanks for this, what's "NSE"? Non standard evaluation?

Comment: Yes. Non standard evaluation. Using some curly-curly or big-bang-operators or something like that I don't understand.

Comment: Ah I see. Yeah dito, I've found it more tricky to truly grasp NSE in an intuitive way

Comment: @DougFir NSE is one of my favorite topics in R you can start from here if you wanna learn more :
https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/index.html

Comment: I had to switch my accepted answer here, the new one just reads more intuitively to me. Thanks all the same for your answer!

Comment: It's okay. 27 Phi 9's answer is great. 

Answer (score 8):

We could use `rename_with` from `dplyr` package and wrap it in a `~case_when` function:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
    rename_with(
        ~ case_when(
        . == "mpg" ~ "MPG",
        . == "cyl" ~ "CYL",
        . == "bla" ~ "uyhgfrtgf",
        TRUE ~ .))
```

```
                     MPG CYL  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

Answer (score 7):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
lookup <-c("MPG" = "mpg", "CYL" = "cyl", "bla" = "uyhgfrtgf")
mtcars %>% 
    rename(!!! lookup[names(.) %in% lookup])
                     MPG CYL  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

names <- c("mpg", "cyl", "sdad")
reps <- c("MPG", "CYL", "BLA")

mtcars %>%
  rename_with(~ str_replace_all(.x, "\\w+", reps[names(mtcars) %in% names]), matches(names))

                   MPG CYL disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: Nice one! But one hint: you shouldn't name your vector `names` since this is the name of an actual function.

Comment: Yes indeed! however they live in two different environments, mine in global and the other in base so they won't affect one another. But yes you are right.

Comment: This is truely right, but some strange structures like `names(names) <- names(reps)` could occure which are... a bit confusing. ;-)

Comment: Yes it's totally not recommended and I was trying so hard to deliver and answer fast :D

Comment: You did answer first! :-)

Comment: No it's not important at all. Your answer is great.